# Does matched pairs design apply to different experiments with the same sample?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, t-test, experiment-design

For instance, we have 50 subjects taking an experiment to test whether diet affects one's health. The same 50 subjects are first monitored of their health for 5 days without a diet plan, and then the same 50 subjects took a diet plan and are monitored for 5 days. Is this an example of a paired matched pairs design?

Comment: Seems you have paired data, but how to test whether the diet plan has any effect relies on the nature of data collected (in 'monitoring') before and after. Not enough information here to say what test to use. // It is as simple at looking at change in weight for each subject?

Comment: Yes, this is a sample of a match paired test since you are monitoring the same test subject before and after treatment.